# Command "doctrine:generate:entities" is not defined

Tags: symfony, doctrine, composer-php, command-line-interface

I encounter a problem with Symfony and the Doctrine entities generator.

When I call `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyCompany`, command fail and throw this exception :

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                            
Command "doctrine:generate:entities" is not defined.  
Did you mean one of these?                            
    doctrine:generate:entity                          
    doctrine:generate:form                            
    doctrine:generate:crud
```

I saw in many post people who had similar problems. But theirs related the `doctrine:generate:entity` command. They had forgotten :

```
"sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*" // in composer.json
```

and

```
new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle(); // in AppKernel
```

In my case everything is OK with composer.json and AppKernel. For example, these commands work : `doctrine:generate:entity`, `doctrine:generate:form` and `doctrine:generate:crud`

But `doctrine:generate:entities` doesn't :/

Here is an extract from my `php app/console list` command :

```
[...]
doctrine
  doctrine:cache:clear-metadata         Clears all metadata cache for an entity manager
  doctrine:cache:clear-query            Clears all query cache for an entity manager
  doctrine:cache:clear-result           Clears result cache for an entity manager
  doctrine:database:create              Creates the configured databases
  doctrine:database:drop                Drops the configured databases
  doctrine:ensure-production-settings   Verify that Doctrine is properly configured for a production environment.
  doctrine:generate:crud                Generates a CRUD based on a Doctrine entity
  doctrine:generate:entity              Generates a new Doctrine entity inside a bundle
  doctrine:generate:form                Generates a form type class based on a Doctrine entity
  doctrine:mapping:convert              Convert mapping information between supported formats.
  doctrine:mapping:import               Imports mapping information from an existing database
  doctrine:mapping:info                 Shows basic information about all mapped entities
  doctrine:query:dql                    Executes arbitrary DQL directly from the command line.
  doctrine:query:sql                    Executes arbitrary SQL directly from the command line.
  doctrine:schema:create                Executes (or dumps) the SQL needed to generate the database schema
  doctrine:schema:drop                  Executes (or dumps) the SQL needed to drop the current database schema
  doctrine:schema:update                Executes (or dumps) the SQL needed to update the database schema to match the current mapping metadata
  doctrine:schema:validate              Validates the doctrine mapping files
[...]
generate
  generate:bundle                       Generates a bundle
  generate:controller                   Generates a controller
  generate:doctrine:crud                Generates a CRUD based on a Doctrine entity
  generate:doctrine:entity              Generates a new Doctrine entity inside a bundle
  generate:doctrine:form                Generates a form type class based on a Doctrine entity
[...]
```

And here some informations about my project vendors versions

```
symfony/symfony                      v2.3.24            The Symfony PHP framework
sensio/framework-extra-bundle        v2.3.4             This bundle provides a way to configure your controllers with annotations
sensio/generator-bundle              v2.3.5             This bundle generates code for you
doctrine/annotations                 v1.2.3             Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                       v1.4.0             Caching library offering an object-oriented API for many cache backends
doctrine/collections                 v1.2               Collections Abstraction library
doctrine/common                      v2.4.2             Common Library for Doctrine projects
doctrine/dbal                        v2.4.4             Database Abstraction Layer
doctrine/doctrine-bundle             v1.2.0             Symfony DoctrineBundle
doctrine/inflector                   v1.0.1             Common String Manipulations with regard to casing and singular/plural rules.
doctrine/lexer                       v1.0.1             Base library for a lexer that can be used in Top-Down, Recursive Descent Parsers.
doctrine/orm                         v2.4.7             Object-Relational-Mapper for PHP
```

Thank's for your help ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the solution to my problem so I post the answer here hopping that it might help somebody one day :)

The command `doctrine:generate:entities` is provided by the file `DoctrineBundle/Command/GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand.php` (https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/v1.2.0/Command/GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand.php). And this file was mysteriously disappeared ! It's weird...

To fix that I deleted `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` folder from vendors and run a `composer update`

Voilà :)